# Why doesn't UInt have a toDouble()?

Tags: kotlin

Consider:

```
val foo: Int = 1
foo.toDouble() // ok

val bar = 2.toUInt()
bar.toDouble() // error!
```

This doesn't make sense to me. Why wouldn't UInt have `toDouble`? (it also doesn't have `.toFloat`).

[The docs say](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html):

> Every number type supports the following conversions:
>
> - toByte(): Byte
> - toShort(): Short
> - toInt(): Int
> - toLong(): Long
> - toFloat(): Float
> - toDouble(): Double
> - toChar(): Char

So it should be possible. The error I get is:

```
Error:(11, 4) Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
@InlineOnly public inline fun String.toDouble(): Double defined in kotlin.text
```

Is UInt not considered a number type? Or is it something else?

Comment: possibly related: some architectures (notably x86) don't have native machine instructions to convert unsigned integers to floating point, only signed.  (AVX512 finally adds that for x86, but it's still not widely available and *very* far from becoming baseline).  Zero-extending to a wider signed integer type is by far the easiest implementation of unsigned->float or double when that's possible, but for 64-bit unsigned integers you need special tricks.  Maybe Kotlin wanted to avoid that?  But given that it runs on top of JVM or Javascript, maybe something else.

Comment: @PeterCordes I doubt that any language would want to restrict itself to a single architecture's shortcomings. I mean even C allows this :) But interesting info nonetheless, thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is UInt not considered a number type?

Yes, it doesn't extend [`Number`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/index.html) class.

Declaration of `Int`:

```
class Int : Number, Comparable<Int>
```

Declaration of `UInt`:

```
inline class UInt : Comparable<UInt>
```

---

**Starting with Kotlin version 1.3.30 `UInt` has `toFloat` and `toDouble` methods.**

Comment: Thanks, that was surprising. Is there a way to convert a `UInt` to a `Double` in some other way?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Try `bar.toLong.toDouble()`

Answer (score 21):

This appears to be coming in 1.3.30, according to [this YouTrack request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27108).

1.3.30 was just [recently tagged](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.3.30) and appears to be releasing very shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Added support in latest version `1.3.30`.

This release ([More](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/04/kotlin-1-3-30-released/)) brings support for more operations for unsigned types and arrays of unsigned types that mirror those for regular number types:

```
fun main() {
    val u1 = 2_147_483_649u
    val u2 = 4_000_000_000u
    println(u1.toDouble())
    println(minOf(u1, u2))

    val array: UIntArray = uintArrayOf(u1, u2)
    println(array.max())
    println(array.all { it > Int.MAX_VALUE.toUInt() })
}
```

> Note: UInt doesn't extend Number class.

```
/**
 * Converts this [UInt] value to [Double].
 *
 * The resulting `Double` value represents the same numerical value as this `UInt`.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun toDouble(): Double = uintToDouble(data)
```